# UWP MediaElement not play music

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am implementing a music player that plays local music files.

I got this error message as my MediaElement failed:

> MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0x80070005

How should I fix it? This is my MediaElement.

```
<MediaElement
    x:Name="MediaPlayer"
    Grid.Column="1"
    AutoPlay="False"
    IsLooping="False"
    MediaEnded="MediaPlayer_MediaEnded"
    MediaFailed="MediaPlayer_MediaFailed"
    Volume="50" />
```

I have tried 3 ways of playing the audio but none of them worked for me.

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(music.Path);
MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(music.Path, UriKind.Absolute);
//MediaPlayer.SetSource(await file.OpenReadAsync(), file.ContentType);
//MediaPlayer.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), file.ContentType);
```

The music.Path (containing path and music filename) is correct because I can load the Album Cover thumbnail. By the way the music file is located at somewhere in the Desktop not in the Assets folder.

I think there is a similar question here: [Mediaelement in Windows 8 Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389227/mediaelement-in-windows-8-metro-app)

But I don't understand why one of the answer is opening a picker. I don't think that would be my solution as I am just playing all the music files under a local folder.

---Update---

I notice that the MediaElement plays music correctly when I am playing an Asset music. So I guess there should be a workaround for playing local music files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. It's pretty simple.

The key part is to have a `StorageFolder` object (in my code it is `CurrentMusicFolder`) containing the music file to be played. For example, I need to play this music file: "C:\MusicFolder\Music.mp3". So I need to do:

```
StorageFolder CurrentMusicFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\MusicFolder");
var file = await CurrentMusicFolder.GetFileAsync("Music.mp3");
MediaPlayer.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), file.ContentType);
MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Note that the path of music is "Music.mp3" instead of "C:\MusicFolder\Music.mp3". You cannot have things like "C:\" in the music path.